# blow-ups and fields of definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over some field $k$, not necessarily algebraically closed. Let $Z$ be a closed subvariety of $X$ which is only defined over an extension of $k$ (e.g. a closed point which is not $k$-rational). Consider the blow-up $\mathrm{Bl}_Z X$ of $X$ along $Z$.

Is $\mathrm{Bl}_Z X$ defined over $k$? I think this is the case but I would appreciate some help to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - blowups are defined intrinsically, without reference to a base field. (See Hartshorne for a full treatment). You can blow up any closed sub*scheme* of a scheme (i.e. you can consider non-reduced structures), and the operation is defined intrinsically, by the relative Proj construction on a graded algebra determined by the corresponding quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals. However, if a subvariety is not rational over $k$, I don't think the blowup will neceasarily have the structure of a variety over $k$.

**Edit: this answers an original form of the question which asked if the blowup is defined at all. See the comments for my thoughts on whether it is defined over $k$: as I'm uncertain, I'll leave this in the comments.**

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why you don't think that the blow-up has a structure of variety over k?

Comment: It's possible I am mistaken because I haven't worked out the equations for blowups of non-rational subvarieties. I believe the problem will be that the equation of the subvariety will have coefficients over the bigger field, and thus (at least in general) the blowup will also be defined by equations in non-rational coefficients and thus be a variety over the larger field but not the smaller one.